# Power Query: How to make a column manual entry for two appended tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery

I am using PQ to automate data in excel. I have a connection to a folder that inputs data into 4 columns once the excel document is added to it. I have appended that data to a single excel document. This document is formatted with the same column headers as the ones in the folder connection. I had to create this excel document separately as it contained data that I did not want to be overwritten with the PQ automation. Everything has been working great, but now I want to change two of the columns in table with the appended data to manual entry. Of course, all the preexisting data does not change in the columns, but all of the data that I type in after the excel document is added to the folder disappears once I refresh.

I tried doing a self-referencing table, but now the rows from the folder connection are duplicating with each refresh. If there is only one row in the folder connect excel file, it will duplicate that one row every time I refresh.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.